# switching to debian 8.2.0 x64 from ubuntu 15.04 x64

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04 x64 and now want to switch to Debian so for that I have prepared a bootable usb stick but I don't want to lose my data that are in /home directory of Ubuntu but also I don't want to use Ubuntu (although it is good OS ).

how can i use the same /home of Ubuntu for Debian like as we have in Windows only by formatting and installing in C: drive we can able to preserve our other disk(ex: D: or E:) with the data.

I have only one way to preserve my data of /home directory and that is to take backup in other usb stick or external hard disk, it would be very good for me if I can preserve it without taking backup in other usb stick or external hard disk cause i have data upto 30 GB in my Ubuntu /home directory and don't have any external hard disk and also my other usb stick is only 8 Gb in size.

Answer (score 0):

Please, give an output of

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

and

```
df -h
```

That will show Your partitions with free and consumed space.
If You have /home in separate partitions, then You are safe to install debian, but have to manually partition the system.
If You don't have separate partition for home folder, than You have to copy it ie to USB:

```
tar czvf /<usb stick mount point>/home_user.tgz /home/<YourUser>
```

After that You can install safely debian nad finaly untar home directory:

```
tar xzvf /<usb stick mount point>/home_user.tgz -C /
```